# Trying to print onto an html page via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo, innerhtml

I'm making a custom WYSIWYG editor with a save function, and through the save function I have run some code to get everything within a certain div, save it into a data table or overwrite it. But right now, I'm trying to load the page back.

The process is as follows: you press the save button, and it runs a PHP script called save.php, which is seen below.

My issue is that I want it to load or echo the contents within a certain div on the original html page. How would I go about doing that? I need it to work like Javascript's innerHTML function, basically.

Below are the files I use, at least the relevant parts.

test.html:

```
<form method="post" name="blog-post" id="blog-post">
        <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="1"><!--Get the post's id-->           
        <div class="blog-editor-bar">
            <a href="#" data-command='save'
                onclick="submitForm('save.php');">
                <i class='fa fa-save'></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="blog-textarea" contenteditable>
        </div>
        <textarea style="display:none;" id="blog-post-cont" name="post-content"></textarea>
</form>
```

test.js:

```
function submitForm(action){
    var theForm = document.getElementById("blog-post");
    theForm.elements("post-content").value = document.getElementById("blog-textarea").innerHTML;
    theForm.action = action;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

save.php:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "<p>Connection Failed:".mysqli_connect_error()."</p>\n";
        }
    //store stuff in database
        //Get Variables
            $postid = $_POST['postID'] ? $_POST['postID'] : null;
            $post = $_POST['post-content'] ? $_POST['post-content'] : null;
    //if exists, overwrite
            if($postid != null || $postid != ""){
                $sqlSave = "SELECT * FROM wysiwyg.post WHERE idpost = $postid";
                $rSave = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlSave) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                if(mysqli_num_rows($rSave)){
                    $sqlOverwrite = "INSERT INTO wysiwyg.post(post) VALUES(?) WHERE idpost = ?";
                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sqlOverwrite);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $post, $postid);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                } else {
                    newSave();
                }
                loadSave();
            }

            function newSave(){
                $sqlNewSave = "INSERT INTO wysiwyg.post(post) VALUES(?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sqlNewSave);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $post);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }

            function loadSave(){
                $sqlLoad = "SELECT * FROM wysiwyg.post WHERE idpost = $postid";
                $rLoad = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlLoad) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                //This is the part I'm stuck on
            }
```

Thank you all in advance for helping me out! I've been stuck on it for at least a few hours!

EDIT: Before people comment on SQL Injections, I have taken it into consideration. This is me getting the code working on my localhost before I run it through a ton of anti-sql injection methods that I have already done in the past. The code i provide is only important to the functionality at this point.

EDIT #2: The anti-injection code already exists. I guess i seem to have forgotten to provide that information. I repeat, the code I have provided here is only code relating to functionality. I have escaped the strings, trimmed, etc. and more, but that code is not necessary to provide for people to get an understanding of what it is i am trying to do.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to save the text. Also your `$sqlSave` and `$sqlLoad` queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use bound parameters for **all** user-supplied data.

Comment: There are many tutorials that go into AJAX, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/. You are partially preventing SQL injections already. You should do it everywhere, doing it later is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mike. Please check my edit. I'm aware of SQL, but currently I'm focusing on functionality first, so making it work. How would i do Ajax from a PHP file, as in at my load php function, how would I call upon an Ajax call to store the values in a json file?

Comment: @chris85 How would I be able to call an ajax request within a php file? I thought I would need to do a javascript file. How would I echo onto that?

Comment: Call the PHP with AJAX then updated the DOM as needed, on the return event. You shouldn't have `a ton of anti-sql injection methods`, separate the input from the query.

Comment: @verdeletg AJAX is done client-side, not server-side. PHP doesn't do AJAX requests. As chris says, it's done by Javascript in the browser.

Comment: @verdeletg Not worrying about SQL injection in the moment you first write the code is very bad practice. It is the time when you have the code fresh on your mind and you don't have to worry about going back through it and hopefully remembering to refactor it. Besides, you already know how to use bound parameters, so it's just a matter of being consistent in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **AJAX request** to communicate with the server, **send data and receive a response**. There are many good tutorials out there, but since I first learned it in W3Schools website I am going to refer you there.

- [JavaScript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).
- [jQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX request which is written like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({                        //start an AJAX call
            type: 'GET',                      //Action: GET or POST
            data: {VariableName: 'GETvalue'},    //Separate each line with a comma
            url: 'Destination.php',           //save.php in your case
                success: function(data)){         //if values send do this 

                    //do whatever

                } 
            }); //end ajax request
        });
    </script>
```

This allows you to send information to your php page without refreshing
So in my example you can do this on the PHP side

```
<?php 

echo $_GET['VariableName'];

?>
```

Will echo out "GETvalue as specified in the data section of the Ajax call"

EDIT************

In the AJAX call you can add dataType if you want json

```
$.ajax({                        
    type: 'GET',                      
    data: {VariableName: 'GETvalue'},   
    dataType: 'json'                   // Allows Json values or you can change it to whatever you want
    url: 'Destination.php',
```

Comment: Please note that the question was not tagged with jQuery. Pure JS AJAX queries are not "made like this".

Comment: @naderbesada what does the data do? i know data type and all the others, but what exactly does data do?

Comment: @Mike you really aren't helping someone trying to identify the problem here. If Jquery is a solution, I'm happy to use it. I get you're a highly reputable community member, but stop.

Comment: @verdeletg Perhaps my tone came off the wrong way, but my point was that this isn't the **only** way to make an AJAX request, as the answer would suggest. It is possible to use pure JS as well.